# How can I create a user without logging in using AngularFire2?

Tags: angularfire2

I want to be able to create users, but from my admin account. So when I use this line:

```
this.af.auth.createUser({email: email, password: password});
```

It creates the user, but then it logs me in as them, and I don't want that. I just want to create it. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

#### Long Answer:

There is no AngularFire 2 way to programatically manage users. The issue is that even if you use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), at least one of the module's dependencies simply won't run in the browser; e.g., webpack.

So you could install the Firebase Admin module with `npm install --save firebase-admin` and then...

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

adminCreateUser() {
    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: "user@example.com",
        emailVerified: false,
        password: "secretPassword",
        displayName: "John Doe",
        photoURL: "http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png",
        disabled: false
    })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
        // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
        console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
    });
}
```

... would likely throw the error `Error: Can't resolve 'dns' in '.../node_modules/isemail/lib'`. The reason for this is explained [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/317).

You could probably figure out some sort of hack for this, but this particular issue raises an important objection to this method of user creation, which has to do with client-side cryptography.

#### Short Answer:

Run the Firebase Admin SDK on a backend service instead.